# React Native Expo offline app database option

Tags: react-native, expo

I was using firebase for react native expo app as backend. My app is just use for browsing data and images. (JSON)Which it is just R in “CRUD” I got around 8000 data. Thats is no point to use firebase as in I couldn’t enjoy the realtime features.

Which database I should use and how can I remote update the data /file